# ASP.Net 1.1 with Wildcard Mapping gives 404 on default documents

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, friendly-url, asp.net-1.1

I have an application where it was requested that a friendly url be made for a dynamic page that uses a lot of query string values.  After some research on the Internet, I found that I needed to create either an HttpModule or HttpHandler to do the routing and then setup a wildcard mapping to the .Net v1.1 of aspnet_isapi.dll in IIS (removing the Verify the File Exist checkbox).

Everything works fine locally on my XP Pro box using a virtual directory to test with.

When I promote it to a test environment (Server 2003), direct access to pages and the routing work fine; however, the default document no longer works.  I found a reference online that states that IIS6 handles the wildcard mapping prior to the default document logic due to the separation of ASP.Net WP and IIS6.

I tried to update my HttpHandler to account for a / route; however, the code behind on the routed pages no longer work.  In the Web.Config I've tried using the path as * as well as / and get the same response.  I'm also using Response.Redirect which I feel is not correct.

I have also tried URLRewriter.net; however, it didn't work after spending a few hours attempting to get it working (it just wouldn't route in this asp.net 1.1 app for some reason).

Any ideas as to what may be the cause or how I could get my routes to the default page and my specific page setup while leaving the rest alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered some typos in the README information for the URLRewriter.  After configuring it based on the online documentation and not the examples that come with the binaries, I was able to get it to work and resolve my issue locally.

After I promoted the code to my testing server, the intended route is working but the default domain route is not still.  I modified the URL Pattern for the default route a little bit and everything started working.